# Setting the orientation to be landscape for large screens

Tags: android, android-layout

I know that in order for me to force the app to be in a certain orientation then I do this in the manifest file for each activity: android:screenOrientation="portrait" 
My question is, if I want to set the orientation to landscape ONLY for large screens, then how can I do it? What I know is that there are layout folders specific for each screen size but what about manifest file? It is common for all screen sizes.
Any suggestions?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check for the device that is being used through the code. A sample code for device checking is:

```
     context.getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK)==4
```

or

```
       Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >=11
```

This code is basically for checkinh if its honeycomb tabor not. After checking this set the orientation through code:

```
          setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
```

Comment: Perfect. Thanks for the answer and different options

Answer (score 0):

Put this in your onCreate of activities..

```
if ((getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout & 
Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK) == 
    Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_LARGE) {
   setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code do so

```
if((getApplicationContext().getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout
                & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK)
                >= Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_LARGE){
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can set orientation in menifest file for particular screen